# google visualization graph type stacked true not working

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

how can I display stacked column graph without using chart type only use id name and I want to display two different variables using one function... is there any problem with stacked column true in option variable? let me know how to optimize my code by using different variable data with same function use without using switch case 
??

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var charts = {};
  var options = {
       isStacked: true,
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 24,
        left: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 48,
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valueSuffix: ' USD',
        valuePrefix: '$'
      },
      vAxis: { 
        title: 'Cost in USD ($)', format:'$#',
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      width: '100%'
    
  };
  //  daily and monthly  stacked columns charts data
  var jsonData = [{"name":"product a","data":[["2018-03-01",18.89034482758612],["2018-03-02",18.89268292682916],["2018-03-05",18.89324503311252],["2018-03-07",18.89268292682916],["2018-03-10",18.89377777777766],["2018-03-11",18.893525179856],["2018-03-12",18.89359999999988],["2018-03-13",18.89311475409824],["2018-03-14",18.89311475409824],["2018-03-15",18.89294117647046],["2018-03-16",18.89272727272716],["2018-03-17",18.89387173396662],["2018-03-18",18.89366292134818],["2018-03-19",18.8923456790122]]},{"name":"product b","data":[["2018-03-01",10.99034482758612],["2018-03-02",1.99268292682916],["2018-03-05",16.99324503311252],["2018-03-07",12.99268292682916],["2018-03-10",12.99377777777766],["2018-03-11",11.993525179856],["2018-03-12",10.99359999999988],["2018-03-13",18.99311475409824],["2018-03-14",18.99311475409824],["2018-03-15",18.99294117647046],["2018-03-16",18.99272727272716],["2018-03-17",18.99387173396662],["2018-03-18",18.99366292134818],["2018-03-19",18.9923456790122]]}];
  loadData(jsonData, '1' );

  var dailystacked = [{"name":"product a","data":[["2018-03-01",18.89034482758612],["2018-03-02",18.89268292682916],["2018-03-05",18.89324503311252],["2018-03-07",18.89268292682916],["2018-03-10",18.89377777777766],["2018-03-11",18.893525179856],["2018-03-12",18.89359999999988],["2018-03-13",18.89311475409824],["2018-03-14",18.89311475409824],["2018-03-15",18.89294117647046],["2018-03-16",18.89272727272716],["2018-03-17",18.89387173396662],["2018-03-18",18.89366292134818],["2018-03-19",18.8923456790122]]},{"name":"product b","data":[["2018-03-01",18.99034482758612],["2018-03-02",18.99268292682916],["2018-03-05",18.99324503311252],["2018-03-07",18.99268292682916],["2018-03-10",18.99377777777766],["2018-03-11",18.993525179856],["2018-03-12",18.99359999999988],["2018-03-13",18.99311475409824],["2018-03-14",18.99311475409824],["2018-03-15",18.99294117647046],["2018-03-16",18.99272727272716],["2018-03-17",18.99387173396662],["2018-03-18",18.99366292134818],["2018-03-19",18.9923456790122]]}];
  loadData(dailystacked, '2');

  // load json and dailystacked data
  function loadData(jsonData, id) {
    // create data table
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date'); 
    
       // add date column
       $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
      // add product column
      var colIndex = dataTable.addColumn('number', product.name);

      // add product data
      $.each(product.data, function(dataIndex, data) {
        var rowIndex = dataTable.addRow();
        dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(data[0]));
        dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, data[1]);
      });
    });
     
    // draw chart
    $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart(id,  dataTable);
    });
    drawChart(id, dataTable);
  }
  // draw chart
  function drawChart(id, dataTable) {
    if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'containerId': 'chart-' + id,
         'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
         
        options:
       {
        'isStacked'   : 'true',
        
    },
      });
    }
    charts[id].setDataTable(dataTable);
    charts[id].draw();
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart-1"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart-2"></div>
```

Comment: change --> `options: options[chartType]` -- to --> `options: options`

Comment: thanks can you help me with last two questions about stacked columns with large data and multiple datasets in one chart which i posted recently?

Comment: hi i cant get proper stack columns with large datasets values... here links for my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070106/google-charts-x-axis-daily-date-not-show-it-stacked-columns

Comment: can you check this  one also ? issue with line graph https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140291/google-linechart-add-line-graph-with-categories-wise-all-categories-in-one-char