# google charts x axis daily date not show it stacked columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, google-visualization

i am using google charts and stacked columns not working properly with large datasets or small data also here you can check code it working but not getting stacked columns data and when i use small datasets then display all small width horizontal columns.can you check my comment code thank you in advance
let me know if you know how to implement with different way ?
i want to a graph looking like an image below
[image]

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // save charts for redraw
  var charts = {};
  var options = {
  isStacked :'true',
    Column: {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 60,
        left: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 48,
        
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      width: '100%'
    },
    Pie: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    }
  };

  // get data
  var jsonData = [{"name":"p1","data":[["2017/01/01",1.539011],["2017/01/02",4.22612],["2017/01/03",9.685247],["2017/01/04",8.535989],["2017/01/14",18.260888],["2017/01/15",57.279945],["2017/01/16",61.24776],["2017/01/17",65.12251399999998],["2017/01/18",69.15200200000001],["2017/01/19",73.13965199999997],["2017/01/20",77.10624],["2017/01/21",81.127521],["2017/01/22",85.04579900000002],["2017/01/23",89.003693],["2017/01/24",92.817327],["2017/01/25",64.12351600000001],["2017/02/04",4.734462000000001],["2017/02/05",17.073667999999998],["2017/02/06",21.047981999999998],["2017/02/07",16.340846]]},{"name":"p2","data":[["2017/01/01",3.4],["2017/01/02",8.8],["2017/01/03",19.4],["2017/01/04",16.9],["2017/01/14",33.8],["2017/01/15",106.19999999999999],["2017/01/16",113.4],["2017/01/17",120.6],["2017/01/18",127.79999999999998],["2017/01/19",135.0],["2017/01/20",142.20000000000002],["2017/01/21",149.5],["2017/01/22",156.6],["2017/01/23",163.79999999999998],["2017/01/24",170.70000000000002],["2017/01/25",118.0],["2017/02/04",9.3],["2017/02/05",32.7],["2017/02/06",39.900000000000006],["2017/02/07",30.6],["2017/04/14",16.6]]},{"name":"p3","data":[["2017/01/01",0.090284],["2017/01/02",0.18148],["2017/01/03",0.36250400000000005],["2017/01/04",0.3223319999999999],["2017/01/14",0.629936],["2017/01/15",1.9858830000000007],["2017/01/16",2.117427],["2017/01/17",2.248054],["2017/01/18",2.3795070000000007],["2017/01/19",2.510548],["2017/01/20",2.6411759999999997],["2017/01/21",2.806806],["2017/01/22",2.9025950000000007],["2017/01/23",3.0344140000000004],["2017/01/24",3.156505],["2017/01/25",2.18585],["2017/02/04",0.200327],["2017/02/05",0.700937],["2017/02/06",0.8522410000000002],["2017/02/07",0.651459]]}];
  
  loadData(jsonData, '0', 'Column');

  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData, id, chartType) {
    // create data table
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    switch (chartType) {
      case 'Column':
        // add date column
        dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');

        $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
          // add product column
          var colIndex = dataTable.addColumn('number', product.name);

          // add product data
          $.each(product.data, function(dataIndex, data) {
            var rowIndex = dataTable.addRow();
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(data[0]));
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, data[1]);
          });
        });
        break;

     
    }

    // draw chart
    $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
    });
    drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
  }

  // draw chart
  function drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable) {
    if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart-' + id,
        options: {
        isstacked :'true'
        }
        
      });
    }
    charts[id].setDataTable(dataTable);
    charts[id].draw();
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart-0"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like `jsonData` isn't actually formatted as JSON. Try this: `var jsonData= [{name: "p1", data: [["2017/02/01", 89.10393140000001], ["2017/03/01", 75.10400523999999], ["2017/04/01", 125.74344595999999], ["2017/05/01", 125.74344595999999]]}, {name: "p2", data: [["2017/02/01", 208440.07953051504], ["2017/03/01", 211302.18984154006], ["2017/04/01", 215023.56479282002], ["2017/05/01", 215023.56479282]]}, {name: "p3", data: [["2017/03/01", 0.0], ["2017/04/01", 0.0], ["2017/05/01", 0.0]]}, {name: "p4", data: [["2017/05/01", 0.0]]}];`

Comment: i tried with this format ..can you look at my code about columns name error something like this

Comment: I'm not getting a column name error. The code executes fine, it just doesn't display exactly as it does in your screenshot.

Comment: yes, i need same as display below in a graph image..when i use more data than stacked columns work fine  but  use few months data that getting a display like a small horizontal line

Comment: can you provice an example of a larger dataset that does work?

Comment: ya sure you can check it below

Comment: you can update your question instead of posting an answer. I don't have a solution yet, but I noticed adding a second date to product d fixes the issue... maybe Google Charts doesn't like something about creating columns based on only one row of data?

Comment: thank you so much but i am new to implement google charts do you have any idea about how can i display data stacked columns with different function as using row data.its work well with all other graph pie and line

Answer (score 1):

to get the chart in the image, you will need to use a `'string'` column for the x-axis, vs. `'date'`

once the data table is built, use a data view to convert the date to a string
afterwards, you will need to group the data on the date string

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // save charts for redraw
  var charts = {};
  var options = {
    isStacked :'true',
    Column: {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 60,
        left: 64,
        right: 32,
        bottom: 48,
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'ddd'
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      width: '100%'
    },
    Pie: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    }
  };
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
  });

  // get data
  var jsonData = [{"name":"p1","data":[["2017/01/01",1.539011],["2017/01/02",4.22612],["2017/01/03",9.685247],["2017/01/04",8.535989],["2017/01/14",18.260888],["2017/01/15",57.279945],["2017/01/16",61.24776],["2017/01/17",65.12251399999998],["2017/01/18",69.15200200000001],["2017/01/19",73.13965199999997],["2017/01/20",77.10624],["2017/01/21",81.127521],["2017/01/22",85.04579900000002],["2017/01/23",89.003693],["2017/01/24",92.817327],["2017/01/25",64.12351600000001],["2017/02/04",4.734462000000001],["2017/02/05",17.073667999999998],["2017/02/06",21.047981999999998],["2017/02/07",16.340846]]},{"name":"p2","data":[["2017/01/01",3.4],["2017/01/02",8.8],["2017/01/03",19.4],["2017/01/04",16.9],["2017/01/14",33.8],["2017/01/15",106.19999999999999],["2017/01/16",113.4],["2017/01/17",120.6],["2017/01/18",127.79999999999998],["2017/01/19",135.0],["2017/01/20",142.20000000000002],["2017/01/21",149.5],["2017/01/22",156.6],["2017/01/23",163.79999999999998],["2017/01/24",170.70000000000002],["2017/01/25",118.0],["2017/02/04",9.3],["2017/02/05",32.7],["2017/02/06",39.900000000000006],["2017/02/07",30.6],["2017/04/14",16.6]]},{"name":"p3","data":[["2017/01/01",0.090284],["2017/01/02",0.18148],["2017/01/03",0.36250400000000005],["2017/01/04",0.3223319999999999],["2017/01/14",0.629936],["2017/01/15",1.9858830000000007],["2017/01/16",2.117427],["2017/01/17",2.248054],["2017/01/18",2.3795070000000007],["2017/01/19",2.510548],["2017/01/20",2.6411759999999997],["2017/01/21",2.806806],["2017/01/22",2.9025950000000007],["2017/01/23",3.0344140000000004],["2017/01/24",3.156505],["2017/01/25",2.18585],["2017/02/04",0.200327],["2017/02/05",0.700937],["2017/02/06",0.8522410000000002],["2017/02/07",0.651459]]}];

  loadData(jsonData, '0', 'Column');

  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData, id, chartType) {
    // create data table
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    switch (chartType) {
      case 'Column':
        // add date column
        dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        var aggColumns = [];
        var viewColumns = [0, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return formatDate.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 0));
          },
          label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(0),
          type: 'string'
        }];

        $.each(jsonData, function(productIndex, product) {
          // add product column
          var colIndex = dataTable.addColumn('number', product.name);
          viewColumns.push(colIndex);
          aggColumns.push({
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
            column: colIndex+1,
            label: dataTable.getColumnLabel(colIndex),
            type: dataTable.getColumnType(colIndex)
          });

          // add product data
          $.each(product.data, function(dataIndex, data) {
            var rowIndex = dataTable.addRow();
            var rowDate = new Date(data[0]);
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(rowDate.getFullYear(), rowDate.getMonth(), 1));
            dataTable.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, data[1]);
          });
        });

        var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);
        var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
          dataView,
          [0, 1],
          aggColumns
        );
        var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(groupData);
        dataView.hideColumns([0]);
        dataTable = dataView;
        break;
    }

    // draw chart
    $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
    });
    drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable);
  }

  // draw chart
  function drawChart(id, chartType, dataTable) {
    if (!charts.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      charts[id] = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart-' + id,
        options: {
          isStacked: true
        }
      });
    }
    charts[id].setDataTable(dataTable);
    charts[id].draw();
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart-0"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much..save my day.i appreciate your work in google visualization ..!

Comment: how can i display daily basis data look like in image everyday date in x-axis ..with same datasets ? can you see my image which i uploaded?

Comment: just change the pattern used in `formatDate` to --> `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Comment: this is due to the format in the array data, need to use mm/dd/yyyy instead of yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: i tried with this format and show start date 2016/12/31 but I did not get range start from 2017/01/01 and also in an array having  2017/01/14,2017/01/15 not show in columns

Comment: how to implement zoom functionality ? explorer is not working in column charts i use this code explorer : 
{
actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
 axis: 'horizontal',
keepInBounds: true,
  maxZoomIn: 4.0
} can you help me ?

Comment: how can i add p2: $4535 sign($) in tooltips? is it possible edit tooltip in GC without add columns?

Comment: you can use a [number formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)...

Comment: small silly question? can I use ControlWrapper as a product name in this charts string as a category work or not? i want to display by product name only in drop down options.  i am talking about... you solved line graph que . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945386/google-charts-graphs-set-legend-value-and-same-color-columns